# PHP: Can't Convert MySQL DateTime to Epoch (with Correct Time of Day)

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3, strtotime, epoch

I'm grabbing a datetime from a MySQL database using php.

In mysql the datetime looks like this:

```
'2004-11-03 06:29:48'
```

The line of my code that get the datetime from the database looks like this:

```
$epochTime = strtotime($row[8]);
```

Php's strtotime function convert this time to the wrong epoch time:

```
1099461600
```

That's incorrect. If you convert this back using http://www.epochconverter.com/ you can see that the time of day that was originally in mysql has been lost:

```
Wed, 03 Nov 2004 06:00:00 GMT
```

How can I get an accurate epoch time that has a specificity that matches the datetime from mysql?

Edits:

I just discovered that mysql is only returning the date (without the time):

```
2004/11/03
```

I've tried to force it return the time using this:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(`FieldDateTime`,'%Y-%m-%d %k:%I:%s') from table where id=1;
```

But this didn't work either; it continues to only return the date (without the time).

Ack! I figured it out. I was specifying the wrong field in my array:

```
$epochTime = strtotime($row[8]);
```

Should have been:

```
$epochTime = strtotime($row[9]);
```

It turns out that `$row[8]` was a formatted date field too, causing my confusion. Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RFHhWL It works for me. I think there is an issue when pulling the date from your database, perhaps it cuts off at the space character. Can you try echoing the $row[8] variable?

Comment: What does your query look like? When I run `$epochTime = strtotime('2004-11-03 06:29:48'); echo $epochTime;` I receive a correct value of `1099484988` as expected.

Comment: @Andy And I get `1099463388` for the same line in your comment.  I suspect locale settings are affecting the result.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running? Which timezone do you have set?

Comment: @Andy Converting `'2004-11-03 06:29:48 GMT'` results in what I got, converting `'2004-11-03 06:29:48 CST'` results in what you got.

Comment: That said, the finale few digits between `GMT` and `CST` are the same because minutes and seconds are the same (only hours have shifted).  So LonnieBest seems to have another issue was well as time zone.

Comment: @Izkata Good point. Mine was in CST.

Comment: What code are you using to grab the datetime from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp_column_name`) AS `timestamp`;
```

Then in PHP:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row['timestamp']);
```

Does this match MySQL?